# Optional console window with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm using PyInstaller (auto-py-to-exe) to generate an exe from my Python project.
The only options here are console or window-based.

Now I am wondering if it is possible to make a window-based exe with an optional console window.
What I mean by that is that it should be possible to close the console without closing the entire program.

Because currently the only two options are to go entirely without a console or to have a console that will end the entire program if is is closed.

Is this even possible?
Would it be possible with other modules (py2exe, cxfreeze)?

Comment: could you make console-less and create the console from inside the code?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh yes that would be possible, but first of all it is quite a bit extra work and I mainly wanted the conosle because it starts immediately and there is no 1-3 sec delay before the first window appears (imports take quite a long time and I can't really display a pseudo-console-window before that)